# Machine does not boot any more, no display output

Tags: boot, display, cpu, motherboard

I have a machine (details below) which I use as a NAS (TrueNAS Core). Couple of days ago, TrueNAS offered to update to the latest version. I agreed, and the machine did not come back online. I only now had the time to attach a screen to the machine, but to my surprise the display turns on when starting the machine, but does not show anything, and the HDD LED only flashes a couple of times.

I have tried with a different HDMI cable, and I have also removed all disks, USB drives, and all but one memory bank (btw, with no memory banks, the display does not even turn on).

One more thing: My mainboard has some fancy LEDs on it, and they start to glow orange as soon as I  switch on the AC. If I then switch on the machine, the LEDs start to pulse slowly after a short while (about every 4s). If I switch off the machine after the next failed boot attempt, the LEDs keep pulsing (they do not appear to return to the steady state from the beginning). I have for the life of me not found any information about this in the manual or web.

Hardware details:

- Asus B450M-A/CSM
- AMD Ryzen 5 3400G (including GPU)
- 2x 8GB Corsair DIMM DDR4-3000
- 2x 16GB SanDisk Ultra Fit (Boot Device)
- 2x 4TB WD Red Plus SA3
- 1x 512GB HDD TOSHIBA MK5061GSYN
- 1x 256GB SSD SAMSUNG MMDOE56G5MXP-0VB

For me, this looks like either mainboard or CPU (both rather new) have a problem. Do you agree? How can I further debug the issue?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: Start with a bootable USB key. If it starts, try to see the disk. If it does not start, it may be the basic machine.

Comment: The machine starts from USB already... But even if I remove all of this, I do not even get an Asus splash screen or something. The screen stays completely black... I think it does not get as far as booting from whatever device.

Comment: It starts (and so shows display) with  USB and that means most  likely the disk drivehas failed.

Comment: I wasn't very clear apparently. I NEVER get any output on the display, be it with or without drives. The difference between having no RAM at all and one memory bank is that without, the display even isn't "activated", i.e., turning on. But if the display turns on, it doesn't show anything. Thus, I fear that this is a problem with the mainboard and/or CPU.

With "starts already from USB" I meant that this is the usual configuration of this machine anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> I NEVER get any output on the display, be it with or without drives
> ...

Your post does clarify.  This means the main board and/or CPU has failed.

Now you need to get the machine serviced, or, if you can, replace the machine.

It may not be economical to repair, so think through carefully and then make a decision from there.